# Spark: Programatic schema dynamic column mapping

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, schema, row

I am trying to go further on  sparkSQLexamample runProgramaticSchemaExample and not able to handle dynamic number of columns. Please see this code where the only change is to specify column mapping for Row in a for loop.

```
  private def runProgrammaticSchemaExample(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._
    // $example on:programmatic_schema$
    // Create an RDD
    val peopleRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")

    // The schema is encoded in a string
    val schemaString = "name age"

    // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
    val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
      .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
    val schema = StructType(fields)

    // Convert records of the RDD (people) to Rows
    val rowRDD = peopleRDD
      .map(_.split(","))
     //       .map(attributes => Row(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim))
      .map(attributes => Row(for (i <- 0 to (attributes.length -1 )){attributes(i)}))

    // Apply the schema to the RDD
    val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

    // Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame
    peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
    peopleDF.printSchema()
    // SQL can be run over a temporary view created using DataFrames
    val results = spark.sql("SELECT name FROM people")

    // The results of SQL queries are DataFrames and support all the normal RDD operations
    // The columns of a row in the result can be accessed by field index or by field name
    results.map(attributes => "Name: " + attributes(0)).show()
    // +-------------+
    // |        value|
    // +-------------+
    // |Name: Michael|
    // |   Name: Andy|
    // | Name: Justin|
    // +-------------+
    // $example off:programmatic_schema$
  }
}
```

Here is the error when I get

```
16/11/15 09:31:06 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true) AS name#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, name)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true) AS age#1
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 1
   :- null
   +- staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType), true)
      +- validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age), StringType)
         +- getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 1, age)
            +- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
               +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:537)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
```

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Allen's answer is good  but I find it somewhat problematic, i modified it and it works:

```
val fieldCount = schemaString.split(" ").length
def getARow(x : Array[String], size : Int) : Row={
  val columnArray = new Array[String](size)
  for (i <- 0 to (size-1)) {
    columnArray(i)=x(i).toString()
  }
  Row.fromSeq(columnArray)
}

val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
val rowRDD = peopleRDD
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(attributes => getARow(attributes,fieldCount))
val peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you and tried to solve it in the same way initially resulting in the same error :) I'm pretty new to scala, but managed to come up with a function to generate that row object (just need to pass a count of your fields).

Get field count:

```
val fieldCount = rdd.map(_.split("\u0001")).map(x => x.size).first()
```

Generate row object function:

```
def getARow(x : Array[String], size : Int) : Row={
val columnArray = new Array[String](size+1)
for (i <- 0 to (size)) {
  columnArray(i)=x(i).toString()
 }
Row.fromSeq(columnArray)
}
```

Create your dataframe using your rdd and schema

```
val myDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map(_.split(delim)).map { x => getARow(x,fieldCount) }, mySchema)
```

Hope this helps somebody!